# What is the most efficient structure to organize buckets in a space partitioning structure on JavaScript - objects or arrays?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I need to create a structure that will partition space of a terrain map in buckets (tiles). I have 2 options. I could store buckets in objects:

```
var bucket = {
    "0,0": [...],
    "0,1": [...],
    "0,2": [...],
    ...
};
var x = 1, y = 2;
var accessed_bucket = bucket[x + "," + y];
```

or I could use an array for this:

```
var width = 512, height = 512;
var bucket = [];
for (var i=0, len=width*height; i<len; ++i)
    bucket[i] = [];
var x = 1, y = 2;
var accessed_bucket = bucket[x % width + y * width];
```

The object option is probably more flexible as I don't have to predefine a width/height. Also I don't need to allocate memory in precedence. But I guess access speed will be slower due to conversion from numbers to string, and the internal hashing algorithm. My question is, is the array option supposed to be faster? If so, how much? What is a good benchmark to test both options?

Edit: as requested by @Niklas B., [this](http://jsperf.com/tilemap-array-hashes) is a benchmark. According to it, arrays are astonishingly faster. I'm not sure this is a relevant benchmark, though.

Comment: What benchmarks have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how to benchmark this.

Comment: We can't really help you there because we don't know the access pattern of your code and all other kinds of important information

Comment: How can I improve the question so you can help me?

Comment: A good starting point would be to set up a http://jsperf.com/ benchmark framework with a bit of testing code that uses the data structure in a way similar to how your application would and with similar data sizes. Then you could include your two options there, compare them and ask for other alternatives here ;) But your question would be very different from what it is now

Comment: @NiklasB. is this what you asked?

Comment: Looks good. In fact the result doesn't surprise me at all. string operations are supposed to be pretty costly, as well as hashing. I edited the benchmark a bit so that it actually does some work with the array elements: http://jsperf.com/tilemap-array-hashes/2 I also added indirection to implement the 2D array. As you can see the differences are much smaller now, so maybe it's not really relevant at all which one you choose. I would go with the array of arrays.

Comment: You are correct in being wary of benchmarking it, it is indeed a hard thing to do. @NiklasB. I fixed your test a big, but it's really hard to fix it and it's unclear what it measures. It also _really_ depends on what you store in the array due to ram line caching, how well the JIT can sniff the array's final length, and what is done with the array (if it's a hash/array/whatever of objects or of basic types has a big impact for example). OP - how big is what you're trying to store? How long do you need to store it for? How 'dynamic' is the data? Also, remember profiling > microbenchmarks :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Very true, but by the feel of it, an array of arrays is probably the "safest" bet, because most of the work is pushed to the runtime (as opposed to doing index calculations or even string operations to build up the key). That argument is probably less relevant in JITed implemetations. Fully agreed that OP needs to test this stuff in the actual application. It's not my test BTW

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm using this to partition space in a world with millions of objects moving all around. So in order not to call my "collision" function O(N^2) times, I need a data structure that allows me to fastly query for elements near certain element, while still allowing fast insertions and updates. This is what I came up with as of now, might help: http://lpaste.net/100757

Comment: @NiklasB. uh huh, I guess that is the case indeed. I'm sketching the structure now, using arrays. Thanks.